# Input value from metabox is not found in $_POST after post save

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, metabox

What I want to do is grab the input from a metabox — a number to be exact — in the post editor area and save it to a custom table I have previously created.

Here it is my code for declaring the metabox for the post type only:

```
function silly_metabox()
{
    $post_types = array( 'post' );

    foreach( $post_types as $type )
    {
        add_meta_box(
            'silly_metabox',
            'Silly Metabox',
            'silly_display_metabox',
            $type
        );
    }
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'silly_metabox' );
```

meanwhile this is where the markup for the metabox is:

```
function silly_display_metabox( $post )
{
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'silly_extrnum_nonce' );

    ?>

    <label for="sillyNum">Silly Number</label>
    <input type="number" id="sillyNum" placeholder="Write a number...">

    <?php
}
```

and last but not least the function to save it all:

```
function silly_save_metabox( $post_id )
{
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );

    $is_valid_nonce = false;

    if ( isset( $_POST[ 'silly_extrnum_nonce' ] ) )
    {
        if ( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'silly_extrnum_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        {
            $is_valid_nonce = true;
        }
    }

    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) return;

    if (array_key_exists( 'sillyNum', $_POST ) )
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix . 'sillydata', array(
            'post_id' => $post_id,
            'silly_number' => $_POST['sillyNum']
        ));
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'silly_save_metabox' );
```

Putting the field sanitization aside for a minute, why the `$_POST` array doesn't contain the `sillyNum` key and the insert operation either fails or doesn't get executed?

Comment: Your input missing the `name` attribute...

Answer (score 0):

The `$_POST['']` has to contain the name attribute of the input field and not the ID.

So to modify your code:

```
function silly_display_metabox( $post )
{
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'silly_extrnum_nonce' );

    ?>

    <label for="sillyNum">Silly Number</label>
    <input type="number" id="sillyNum" name="sillyNum" placeholder="Write a number...">

    <?php
}
```

And

```
function silly_save_metabox( $post_id )
{
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );

    $is_valid_nonce = false;

    if ( isset( $_POST[ 'silly_extrnum_nonce' ] ) )
    {
        if ( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'silly_extrnum_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        {
            $is_valid_nonce = true;
        }
    }

    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) return;

    if (array_key_exists( 'sillyNum', $_POST ) )
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix . 'sillydata', array(
            'post_id' => $post_id,
            'silly_number' => $_POST['sillyNum']
        ));
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'silly_save_metabox' );
```

Let me know if this helps.